Formatting debugging output in the IntelliJ console
I copied this debugging output from the IntelliJ console into Notepad++ and made a macro to make a newline at ever \r\n:
Does IntelliJ ( I'm new to it ) have anything similar for formatting console ouput to be more readable?
The console output
\r\n      Did not match:\r\n         - Management Port actual port type (SAME) did not match required type (DIFFERENT) (OnManagementPortCondition)\r\n\r\n   WebServicesAutoConfiguration#wsdlDefinitionBeanFactoryPostProcessor:\r\n      Did not match:\r\n         - WSDL locations did not find property spring.webservices.wsdl-locations (OnWsdlLocationsCondition)\r\n\r\n   WebSessionIdResolverAutoConfiguration:\r\n      Did not match:\r\n         - @ConditionalOnWebApplication did not find reactive web application classes (OnWebApplicationCondition)\r\n\r\n   WebSocketMessagingAutoConfiguration:\r\n      Did not match:\r\n         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer' (OnClassCondition)\r\n\r\n   WebSocketReactiveAutoConfiguration:\r\n      Did not match:\r\n         - @ConditionalOnWebApplication did not find reactive web application classes (OnWebApplicationCondition)\r\n\r\n   WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration.Jetty10WebSocketConfiguration:\r\n      Did not match:\r\n         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.javax.server.internal.JavaxWebSocketServerContainer', 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.JettyWebSocketServerContainer' (OnClassCondition)\r\n\r\n   WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration.JettyWebSocketConfiguration:\r\n      Did not match:\r\n         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer' (OnClassCondition)\r\n\r\n   WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration.UndertowWebSocketConfiguration:\r\n      Did not match:\r\n         - @
